# Assertion Failure _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Does anyone know why this occurs?  Do I need to update my data source in my `UICollectionView`?

I have 20 cells, the first being unlocked with a number.

The other 19 have locks.  Two separate images are used for that.

When I complete level 1 (in `GameViewController`), and move on to level 2 (still part of `GameViewController`), my Core Data entity `levelLocked` (which, for level one is 0 because it isn't locked), goes from 1 to 0 for level two (meaning it now is unlocked).

If I go back to `UICollectionView`, the part where I change the cell for 2 to show the number not a lock does not work.  Furthermore, if I go back a view controller further to `LevelSelectViewController`, and reenter the `UICollectionView`, I receive the Assertion Failure you see in the title of this post.

Do I need to reload the data? Or delete the data from the data source, then reload?

Comment: Go to this post I had written a couple hours before this one.  It has the code.  I'll signal a comment on there just to confirm.  "Assertion Failure in UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:"

Comment: to "kb920", ........is that it?